# Corpo da requisição (req.body) retornando objeto vazio ao enviar formulário

Tags: javascript, api, express.js

Eu tenho basicamente dois arquivos. O HTML, assim:

```html
<form action="/result", method="POST">
  <input id="phrase" type="text" name="phrase" value="Processar frase" />
  <input type="submit" value="Processar!" />
</form>
```

E uma aplicação Express:

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/result', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.body);
});
```

Basicamente, quando envio qualquer dado pelo formulário, o *endpoint* `/result` retorna um objeto vazio para `req.body`:

```
{}
```

Ao invés de retornar o valor passado no campo do formulário, tal como eu esperava. Já tentei diversas formas e vi muita gente falando de usar o *body-parser*, porém, vi também que ele está depreciado, por essa razão eu prefiro não usar.

Por que não estou recebendo os dados como esperado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está utilizando o *middleware* incorreto.

Formulários HTML, isto é, os elementos `<form>`, por padrão enviam os dados submetidos pelo usuário no corpo da requisição com o *Content-Type* `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Existem dois outras configurações possíveis, de acordo com o valor do atributo [`enctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype).

Agora repare que a sua aplicação está utilizando o *middleware* `express.json()` que espera o corpo da requisição sob o *Content-Type* `application/json`. Formulários HTML não suportam esse formato.

Portanto, altere o *middleware* para o valor adequado que você está enviando. Nesse caso, faça:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Não deixe de consultar a [documentação](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) desse *middleware*.